# Prevent modifying http response headers in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, nginx

I have ran a security scan in my website and scan report showing security thread in below URL, saying "HTTP header injection vulnerability in REST-style parameter to /catalog/product/view/id"

The following URL adding the custom header **XSaint:test/planting-a-stake/category/99** in HTTP Response header.(See the last line in Response Header)

I tried different solutions but no luck! Can any one suggest me to prevent the modifying HTTP Response header.

URL: /catalog/product/view/id/1256/x%0D%0AXSaint:%20test/planting-a-stake/category/99

Response Header:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:253
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Fri, 26 May 2017 11:27:12 GMT
Expires:Sun, 25 Jun 2017 11:27:12 GMT
Location:https://www.xxxxxx.com/catalog/product/view/id/1256/x
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
XSaint:test/planting-a-stake/category/99
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP header injection vulnerability is related to someone injecting data in your application that can be used to insert arbitrary headers (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

In this specific case, the scanner assume the vulnerability might come from the URI put in the Location header:

```
Location:https://www.xxxxxx.com/catalog/product/view/id/1256/x
```

The need here is to ensure that the data put into this URI cannot embed the line return characters, to quote the OWASP HTTP Response Splitting page:

> CR (carriage return, also given by %0d or \r)
>
> LF (line feed, also given by %0a or \n)